# package org.aspectj.lang does not exist - Aspectj

Tags: java, xml, ant, aspectj

I'm new to soft. engineering and doing a project for user management and inside of Security package, I have a class called `SecurityAspects` where I define `@Pointcut` and `@Around`.

I'm using **Apache Ant** to compile the whole program.

**SecurityAspects.java**

```
package teste.servicepack.security.logic;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import teste.domain.UserSession;
import teste.servicepack.security.SecurityContextProvider;
import teste.servicepack.security.logic.Exception.FailRoleException;
import teste.servicepack.security.logic.Exception.NotAuthenticatedException;
import teste.servicepack.security.logic.Permission.HasRole;
import teste.utils.HibernateUtils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Aspect
public class SecurityAspects {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(String.valueOf(SecurityAspects.class));

    @Pointcut("@annotation(Transaction)")
    public void TransactionPointCut(){}

    @Pointcut("@annotation(IsAuthenticated)")
    public void isAuthenticatedPointCut(){}

    @Pointcut("@annotation(hasRole)")
    public void hasRolePointCut(HasRole hasRole){}


    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void executionPointCut(){}


    //Transaction
    @Around("TransactionPointCut() && executionPointCut()")
    public Object transactionAdvise(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
        HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        try {
            Object obj = pjp.proceed();
            HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
            logger.info("Transaction finished successfully!");
            return obj;
        }catch (Exception e){
            HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    // isAuthenticated
    @Around("isAuthenticatedPointCut() && executionPointCut()")
    public Object isAuthenticatedAdvise(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable
    {

        logger.info("isAuthenticated");
        String cookie = SecurityContextProvider.getInstance().getSecuritySessionContext().getRequester();
        UserSession session = (UserSession) HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().load(UserSession.class,cookie);

        if(session.getUser() != null)
            return pjp.proceed();
        throw new NotAuthenticatedException("Access Denied, not authenticated at " + pjp.getSourceLocation().getFileName() + " " + pjp.getSourceLocation().getLine() + " service: " + pjp.getSignature().getName());
    }


    // HasRole
    @Around("hasRolePointCut(hasRole) && executionPointCut()")
    public Object hasRoleAdvise(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,HasRole hasRole) throws Throwable
    {
        logger.info("hasRole");


        String cookie = SecurityContextProvider.getInstance().getSecuritySessionContext().getRequester();

        UserSession session = (UserSession) HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().load(UserSession.class,cookie);

        String[] rolesIn = hasRole.role().split(",");
        String[] roles = session.getUser().getRoles().split(",");

        for(String checkRole: rolesIn){
            if(Arrays.asList(roles).contains(checkRole)) {
                return pjp.proceed();
            }
        }
        throw new FailRoleException("Access Denied, does not have role " + hasRole.role() + " at " + pjp.getSourceLocation().getFileName() + " " + pjp.getSourceLocation().getLine() + " service: " + pjp.getSignature().getName());
    }



}
```

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project default="deploy" basedir=".">

    <property file="local.properties"/>
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <path id="pathref">

        <fileset dir="lib/hibernate">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="lib/mysql">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="lib/commons">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="lib/log4j">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="lib/json">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib">
            <include name="servlet-api.jar"/>
        </fileset>


    </path>

    <taskdef name="hibernatetool"
             classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask"
             classpathref="pathref" classpath="${build.dir.classes}"/>
    <taskdef name="schemaupdate"
             classname="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdateTask"
             classpathref="pathref" classpath="${build.dir.classes}"/>



    <target name="generateUpdateHibernateSql" depends="compile">
        <schemaupdate
                properties="${build.dir.classes}/teste/domain/jdbc.properties"
                quiet="no"
                text="no">
            <fileset dir="src/java">
                <include name="**/*.hbm.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </schemaupdate>
    </target>

    <target name="generateHibernateDomainObjects">
        <mkdir dir="src/gen"/>
        <replace dir="src/java" value="">
            <include name="**/*.hbm.xml"/>
            <replacefilter token='&lt;timestamp source="db"' value="&lt;timestamp"/>
        </replace>
        <hibernatetool>
            <configuration>
                <fileset dir="src/java">
                    <include name="**/*.hbm.xml"/>
                </fileset>
            </configuration>
            <hbm2java
                    jdk5="true"
                    ejb3="false"
                    destdir="src/gen"/>
        </hibernatetool>
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="src/gen">
                <include name="**/*Impl.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </delete>
        <replace dir="src/java" value="">
            <include name="**/*.hbm.xml"/>
            <replacefilter token='&lt;timestamp' value='&lt;timestamp source="db"'/>
        </replace>
    </target>


    <target name="initDirs">
        <mkdir dir="build"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/ant"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/ant/classes"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/ant/war"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/ant/war/WEB-INF"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/ant/war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/ant/war/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </target>


    <target name="deploy" depends="build.war">
        <copy todir="${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/">
            <fileset dir="build/ant/">
                <include name="war/**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <touch file="${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/war/WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build.war" depends="compile">
        <copy todir="build/ant/war/WEB-INF" file="conf/web.xml"/>
        <copy todir="build/ant/war">
            <fileset dir="src/web">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>

        <copy todir="build/ant/war/WEB-INF/classes">
            <fileset dir="build/ant/classes">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>

        <copy todir="build/ant/war/WEB-INF/lib">
            <fileset dir="lib/hibernate">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="lib/mysql">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="lib/log4j">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="lib/commons">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="lib/json">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <touch file="build/ant/war/WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
    </target>

    <target name="war" depends="build.war">
        <war file="build/ant/war.war">
            <fileset dir="build/ant/war">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="initDirs">
        <javac destdir="build/ant/classes"
               debug="true"
               encoding="UTF-8"
               source="1.8" target="1.8"
               classpathref="pathref">
            <src path="src/java"/>
            <src path="src/gen"/>
        </javac>
        <copy file="conf/log4j.properties" todir="build/ant/classes"/>
        <copy file="conf/hibernate.cfg.xml" todir="build/ant/classes/teste/domain"/>

        <copy todir="build/ant/classes">
            <fileset dir="src/java">
                <include name="**/*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>



        <copy file="conf/jdbc.properties" todir="${build.dir.classes}/teste/domain"/>
        <replace file="${build.dir.classes}/teste/domain/jdbc.properties">
            <replacefilter token="@database.username@" value="${database.username}"/>
            <replacefilter token="@database.password@" value="${database.password}"/>
            <replacefilter token="@database.connection.url@" value="${database.connection.url}"/>
        </replace>
        <replace file="${build.dir.classes}/teste/domain/hibernate.cfg.xml">
            <replacefilter token="@database.username@" value="${database.username}"/>
            <replacefilter token="@database.password@" value="${database.password}"/>
            <replacefilter token="@database.connection.url@" value="${database.connection.url}"/>
            <replacefilter token="@hibernate.show.sql@" value="${hibernate.show.sql}"/>
        </replace>
    </target>

</project>
```

But my problem is, when I try to compile with Ant, I have this error:

```
/Users/dilantaskin/Downloads/TrabalhoES/src/java/teste/servicepack/security/logic/SecurityAspects.java:3: error: package org.aspectj.lang does not exist
/Users/dilantaskin/Downloads/TrabalhoES/src/java/teste/servicepack/security/logic/SecurityAspects.java:4: error: package org.aspectj.lang.annotation does not exist
```

Like that I have over 20 errors just because of **org.aspectj.lang**.

In ide, everything looks fine, nothing stays red like it doesn't support.

I can see that I have **aspectjrt.jar** and **aspectj-1.9.7** inside of External Libraries.

I tried to change the **org.aspectj.lang** to **org.aspectj.lang3** but it doesn't recognize.

Can anyone explain me why do I get errors even though I have necessary jars?

**INFO:** Im not using `Maven` and I think(?) neither `Spring`. I have a basic `Java` project on `IntelliJ` using `Tomcat`, `Hibernate`, `Servlet` and `Ant`.

---

**Edit by kriegaex:** The author shared an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub under [Edifie/user-management-NF](https://github.com/Edifie/user-management-NF), making the problem reproducible (if first you also download and unzip Tomcat, then point the Ant build to it).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be advised to extend your question to contain an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In concrete terms, you are asking about Ant but do not provide the Ant build script and an example application which I can compile. Ideally, publish a full minimal example project on GitHub and link to it, then notify me with a comment. Besides, as a beginner in software engineering I recommend you to learn Maven, because Ant IMO is a pain in the ***. Don't even try to wire your brain to thinking in terms of scripted builds.

Comment: Besides, what is `org.aspectj.lang3` supposed to mean? One more thing: In your aspect, I see pointcuts `@annotation(Transaction)` and `@annotation(IsAuthenticated)`, without binding the annotation to a pointcut parameter like you did for `@annotation(hasRole)`. Literal annotation names need to be fully qualified in annotation-style AspectJ, except for the special case that the annotation is in the exact same package as the aspect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @kriegaex! I uploaded build.xml and here is the github link for the project: https://github.com/Edifie/user-management-NF

Comment: `org.aspectj.lang3`is a solution that i tried that i saw in here: https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-fix-commons-lang-package-does-not-exist-error-db4051b8a46b

Comment: Where are you adding the aspectj JARs to the buildpath ("pathref") and the WAR file?

Comment: That article describes an update from an older Commons Lang version to Commons Lang 3. Did you read the final paragraph? _"Why? Basically, Commons Lang 3.x brought in this new package naming with the 3 in lang3."_ That solution does **not** apply to AspectJ. Please try to understand what you are reading before changing your source code. "Copy & paste programming" is not helpful. "Programming by Stack Overflow" is not, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected [your project on GitHub](https://github.com/Edifie/user-management-NF), thanks for the link. There is so much wrong with it, I hardly know where to begin:

1. You committed library JARs instead of doing proper dependency management using Maven, Gradle or, if you insist to stay on Ant, something like Ivy. Dependencies should be downloaded during the build, not committed into a source code management (SCM) repository. Using Maven or Gradle also would have the advantage that IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse can automatically import your projects and also know where to find the dependencies and share them between projects, instead of you redundantly committing them to each of your project SCM repositories and manually adding them to your IDE project configuration. That is just ugly.
2. One of the JARs in your project is `aspectj-1.9.6.jar`. This is not what you want but an executable installer, the purpose of which is to install AspectJ locally. In there, you also find nested JARs such as `aspectjrt.jar` (runtime), `aspectjtools.jar` (compiler), `aspectjweaver.jar` (load-time weaving agent). You would have to execute that installer and then copy the libraries you need to your `lib` directory.
3. In order for the Java compiler to recognise your AspectJ imports, you need the AspectJ runtime on your classpath, i.e. you can download [`aspectjrt-1.9.6.jar`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.9.6/jar) from Maven Central (select "Downloads → jar" in the top right menu). Then you simply copy it to `lib` and add this to your Ant script:

   ```xml
   <fileset dir="lib">
     <include name="aspectjrt*.jar"/>
   </fileset>
   ```
4. Now the project compiles, but if that achieves what you want depends on whether you want to use Spring AOP or native AspectJ. For the former, no AspectJ compiler is necessary, but your aspects would have to be made Spring components. For the latter, compiling with `javac` is not enough, you need the AspectJ compiler `ajc`. AspectJ provides its own [Ant task](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/antTasks.html) for that. If you need the Ant task, you also want to have the AspectJ compiler on that task's classpath (not on the application classpath, only during build time). That would be [`aspectjtools-1.9.6.jar`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools/1.9.6/jar).

I am not an Ant user, so I have zero interest in this ancient build tool, but if you are an Ant user, you will know how to finish the job.

There is more wrong with your application, e.g. like I said in my comment, `@annotation(Transaction)` and `@annotation(IsAuthenticated)` should use fully qualified class names or import the classes and bind the annotations to pointcut parameters, if that is what you need.

I think, you should take a break and learn some Ant and AspectJ basics first, probably also Git basics. Or if you have a choice to switch from Ant to Maven, I strongly advise you to do that and forget Ant. If you are stuck with Ant because your employer requires you to use it, my sincere condolences. But actually, it is just a tool, and if you need it, just learn how to handle it.

P.S.: The current version of AspectJ is 1.9.8. If you like, you can upgrade.

Comment: Thank you so much! the aspectjrt and including it to "pathref" solved my problem! This is a project for one of my classes, so that's why for now, we need to use Ant. But thanks for the suggestions! Saved me a lot!

Comment: Happy to help. I actually always feel uncomfortable to speculate, but your example project was definitely a better basis for an educated guess than just your original question. Good luck with your class.